# Check matching values using php pregmatch

Tags: php

How to check matching value using `preg_match` in PHP. Could you please check below samples and help me write a regular expression?

```
Sample values are 
1: sam.s_655
2: sara.t_993
3: suyathi.s_633
4: siraj.t_912

<?php

    $val = 'sara.t_993';
    if (preg_match('', $val)) {
        print "Got match!\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: What is the match you want to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$val = "sara.t_993";

if (preg_match('#^[a-z]+\.[a-z]{1}_[0-9]{3}$#', $val)) {
    print "Got match!\n";
}
```

[a-z]+   = one or more a-z

\.  = one dot, dot must be escaped, is a special char in regex

[a-z]{1} = one a-z

_ =  one undercore

[0-9]{3} = three numbers

^ ... $  = for full match , so **siraj.t_912abc** wont match

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works so code is preg_match('#^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\_[0-9]{3}$#', "sam.pm_993"). Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Yes, if after the dot one or more chars are possible , then you can use + instead of a fixed number:  +  is the same as {1,}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the match you are looking for:

```
preg_match('/^\w*\.\w\_\d{3}$/', $look);
```

Comment: Thank you it also works. preg_match('/^\w*\.\w*\_\d{3}$/', "sam.ks_237")